# No se me Elimina el Item de mi RecyclerView

Tags: android, arraylist, recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Tengo un RecyclerView que me devuelve un ArrayList, el problema es que no me elimina el item que estoy seleccionando mediante el botón eliminar, no me lanza ningún error, solo me sale el servicio se elimino, pero no lo elimina.

De antemano le agradezco su ayuda.

***Este es mi Adaptador donde realizo el método de eliminar el item***

```
 public ViewHolderCarrito onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_carro_compras,null,false);

                eliminar_servicio = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_server);
                eliminar_servicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View view) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                        builder.setMessage("Está seguro que desea eliminar el servicio ?");
                        builder.setTitle("Te Informa: ");
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.iconrasel);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                onLongClick(view); //Método delete item
                                Toast t=Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"El Servicio ha sido eliminado...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                t.show();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });



                return (new ViewHolderCarrito(view));
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        final  ViewHolderCarrito holderCarrito = new ViewHolderCarrito(view);
        int position = holderCarrito.getAdapterPosition();
        if(position!=-1) {

            carroCompra.remove(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, carroCompra.size());
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            holderCarrito.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderCarrito holder, int position) {
        holder.nombre_servicio.setText(carroCompra.get(position).getNombre_servicio());
        holder.precio_servicio.setText(""+carroCompra.get(position).getPrecio_servicio());
        holder.imagen_servicio.setImageResource(carroCompra.get(position).getImagen_servicio());
```

Nota: El ArrayList del Recycler se realizo con sharedPreferences

Comment: Es que no puedes llamar al `onLongClick` así porque no ejecutaría el `onLongClick` que tu quieres, sino el de la clase del objeto `eliminar_servicio` que es donde estás metido. Y como no lo tienes implementado, te estará ejecutando el de la clase base que no hace nada. Las funciones `onLoQueSea`, son callbacks de Android, no son para que las llames tú explícitamente. Tendrás que implementar otra función tuya que haga el remove y llamarla allí donde la necesites.

Comment: Estimado. 
Gracias por el comentario, la verdad soy novato en esto, me podria dar una guía de como lo puedo resolver este problema, como implemento esa función.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que lo estas realizando casí correctamente, debes también llamar el método  [**notifyItemRangeChanged** (int positionStart, int itemCount)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemrangechanged_1) , de esta forma:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    final  ViewHolderCarrito holderCarrito = new ViewHolderCarrito(view);
    int position = holderCarrito.getAdapterPosition();
    if(position!=-1) {

        carroCompra.remove(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, carroCompra.size());
        notifyItemRemoved(position);

        //* Agrega notifyItemRangeChanged()
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, carroCompra.size());

        holderCarrito.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    return true;
}
```

> [notifyItemRangeChanged (int positionStart, 
>                   int itemCount)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemrangechanged_1) Notifica a los observadores registrados que los elementos `ItemCount` que comienzan en la posición
>   `positionStart` han cambiado.

Comment: Estimado, nuevamente gracias por el comentario ,puse  le agregue el  notifyItemRangeChanged(position, carroCompra.size());, pero al parecer no se borra del shared preference

Comment: ¿Que tienes guardado en preferencias? Si tienes los elementos de carroCompra, agrega como lo construye este listado. Simplemente tienes que realizar un método que elimine el elemento del listado en base a su indice (position).

Comment: Esto tengo en Preferencias
public void onClick(View v) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(carro_compra);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("server_peluqueria_estetica",json);
                editor.apply();
                Fragment carritoFragment = new CarritoFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, carritoFragment).commit(); }

Comment: ese código pertenece a mi fragmento de productos donde los guardo con shared preferences

Comment: ah ahora veo, lo que estas usando es un json y este lo guardas en preferencias, regularmente el llenado de elementos en un RecyclerView proviene de una petición, no de un archivo estático. En este caso me parece algo amplia la pregunta, que te parece si agregas otra pregunta de "como eliminar un elemento de un archivo json que es guardado en preferencias" ?

Comment: Listo estimado, ya voy a volver a preguntar y agregar mas código

Comment: @TonyOrmaza si esta respuesta soluciono el problema recuerda marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.